# Asterisk server connected to ATA adapter needs to be always powered on?

Tags: asterisk, voip, ethernet, telephony, ata

my setup would look like this:

- ubunutu linux pc running Asterisk Server
- analog phone connected to the VOIP ATA adapter
- VOIP ATA adapter connected to Asterisk Server via Ethernet

I have only found information about setting up an extension within the Asterisk Server for the ATA. Here the SIP account for the phone is configured within Asterisk, it becomes clear to me that the Asterisk Server needs to be powered on at all times, otherwise the ATA won't be able to send/receive any phone calls.

### My Question

Is it possible to let the ATA adapter store and manage the SIP accounts while the Asterisk Server monitors incoming calls (I need the called id) and also can send a desired phone number to the ATA to initiate an outgoing call. With this even if the Asterisk Server is powered down the user still is able to make/receive calls via the ATA adapter using the analog phone. If this is possible, could you please give me a reference or hint how to setup the Asterisk extension for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you have linksys adapters, you can create dialplan on adapters to callout directly other adapter(with static ip) in case if server is down.

On most adapters you can use backup proxy if primary proxy failed

Thats all.

In most case if your server is down, you have no phone service

Comment: Hi arheops, thank you for your reply! Since all ATA adapters can work on their own, provided a SIP Account is registered/attached to it, I was wondering if it would be possible to automate the ATA: if it finds a working proxy (Asterisk Server is running) it will connect to it, otherwise if no proxy can be found (Server down), it will register to the SIP Account that was previously stored on itself.

Comment: so you thinks this is doable? I didn't quite understand your reply.